# Why is the biography of comedian Andy Kaufman titled "Man on the Moon"?

Tags: title, man-on-the-moon

From seeing the title *Man on the Moon*, I thought the movie was going to be related to the **Earth's Moon** like *Apollo 13*.

But the movie is a biography / comedy-drama.

Why does the movie have this title?

Comment: Out of interest, Kaufman never considered himself a 'comedian'. "I am not a comic, I have never told a joke. ... The comedian's promise is that he will go out there and make you laugh with him. ... My only promise is that I will try to entertain you as best I can."

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This title is taken from 1992 song *Man on the Moon* that was written by the band [R.E.M.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.E.M.) who also created the soundtrack of this film.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Moon_(film)#Music)

> The soundtrack for the film was written by rock band R.E.M., whose 1992 song "Man on the Moon" (originally written in honor of Kaufman) gave the film its title.

This song belongs to an R.E.M. song about Andy Kaufman from their album [Automatic For The People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_for_the_People).

Since this is a biography (with a few changes) of [Andy Kaufman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Kaufman), maybe this is a way to honor him by taking the title of his movie from a song about him.

The title  of the song [Man on the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Moon_(song)), and chorus **refer to the moon landing conspiracy theories as an oblique allusion to rumors that Kaufman's death in 1984 was faked.**

Comment: You may want to elaborate on why the song is titled this way.

Comment: Though it doesn't require, but I did.

Comment: @AJ Thanks for adding it, I *do* think it’s required because your answer would otherwise be much less useful (compare “why are you here?” — “because I was born”). The question was clearly about what the title signifies.

Comment: I thought Andy was a disbeliever in the Moon landings?

Comment: @KevinDTimm This reminds me of the scene in Interstellar where Cobb listens to a teacher at the local school describe how the book he gave his daughter had been replaced by one which correctly described the Apollo missions as an elaborate hoax to force the Soviet bloc to spend themselves into bankruptcy.  McConaughey's portrayal of the reaction is a lot less than I would have had, but priceless all the same.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I'm not sure if there's any evidence one way or another, but there is a common saying, "If they can put a man on the moon, then..." followed by a justification that something thought to be impossible was actually feasible.  For instance, faking one's own death.  See also: Bill Hicks

Comment: [Congratulations, for the 2nd runner up Rewards for 1st quarter of 2017](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2724/1190)

Answer (score 2):

The term comes from a journalism theory that states:
The more a topic appears in the news, the less people attention it would get, specially, compare to the first time that the topic has been broadcasted in the news.
The best example of this theory is the news about landing of a person on the moon, or "Man on the moon". The first landing got the attention of the entire world. Although, after multiple landing, very few people cared about the landing news.
This is what had happened to "Kaufman" life and his career. As film shows, whenever he found his shows became the "Man on the Moon", he changed his shows topics, or even shut them down.